# What is the animal adjective relating to tegu lizards (salvatorine, tupinambine etc.)?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, terminology, word-formation, animals

If I were to go on a "corvine extermination expedition," we would understand an intent to exterminate crows, of genus corvus. The invasive tegu lizards in Florida are subject to such expeditions today. They are of the genus Tupinambis or Salvator depending on the source. What would be the most suitable adjective for such a tegu lizard hunting expedition according to modern conventions?

Answer (score 4):

Neither the extermination nor the expedition are **corvine** – the prey is. I would say

> a [corvid](https://www.lexico.com/definition/corvid) extermination expedition
> a [tegu](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tegu) extermination expedition

This can be exposed with these sentences

> I bought some <strike>catlike</strike> cat food today
> I went on a <strike>catlike</strike> cat rescue mission today

Comment: I see, I formed my question according to my need but badly represented it in the example, which was arbitrary. I was in fact looking to describe a leather fashioned from the tegu hide, but it seemed too complicated a question. So, "a catlike leather" was in fact what I intended in the title question. Sorry.

Comment: The same applies: **cat skin**, not catlike skin. These are compound nouns.

Comment: Could that nuance be added to the answer? I think it was clear I was after the adjective to describe the thing sought rather than the activity. Pardon my incorrectly used example, the adjective relating to the question could be added and the answer would help distinguish this nuance.

Comment: @VogonPoet Feel free to edit the question. To WeatherVane: To play devil's advocate, wouldn't the phrase "feline food" be conceivable? But back to VogonPoet, I'd warn that any word so obscure that we can't even agree about how to invent it would be something that obscures rather than conveys meaning. The only uses I can imagine would be to first let your context identify the lizards clearly, and then deploy this new word as a tongue-in-cheek bit of show-offy wordplay—which not only is a bit obnoxious, but would backfire if your audience doesn't know the lizards' scientific name.

Comment: @AndyBonner I imagine scientists have a convention for such things and this was the standard I hoped to discover here. As to editing myself, well, the question remains unanswered so I can’t. As to the obscurity, it is intended for literature, and the character is a bit bombastic. It serves the purpose you say.

Comment: @VogonPoet Sorry, I should have clarified: You can use the small "Edit" link under the question to update it at any time.

Comment: Oh I am familiar from other stacks; but again, The title question has no answer to insert yet.

Comment: As the question mentions two versions of the tegu lizard, isn't the most suitable adjective the one you are going to hunt?

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't think so: it is the cat that is feline, not what it eats.

Comment: I just mean, while a leading definition of feline seems to be "catlike," I also see "[of, relating to, or affecting cats](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feline)"; similar for bovine and canine. While I do believe that "of the tegu lizard" is a more reasonable choice for the OP, I don't know that the " Xine " formation can only be equated with "X-like".

Comment: @AndyBonner I see what you mean: human food is fit for humans, not sustenance for cannibals.

Comment: Except for Soylent Green...

Answer (score 2):

*Tegu* is an uncommon animal to start with, and the usage of the word is very uncommon within the English language as well (*esp.* in common parlance). Expecting an animal adjective for a tegu would be too optimistic, unless it is used within an isolated zoological context; where I would expect an adjective for tegu to be rare even in zoology, herpetology and saurology, and moreover, is possibly not even needed in most cases. *OED* gives *tegu* as a synonym and a shortened version of *teguexin*; and the frequency band of the usage of both words is Band 2. Here is what *OED* says for Frequency Band 2:

> Band 2 contains words which occur fewer than 0.01 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These are almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people. Many are technical terms from specialized discourses.

On the other hand, you already came up with the right formation of the would-be adjectives for tegus, *salvatorine* and *tupinambine*; where they are formed based on the genus name of tegus, *Salvator* or *Tupinambis*. Another option could be *teguine* which is short, direct and easy to understand. Out of these three adjectives, only *tupinambine* has the relevant usage in a few results in zoology context per google search. *Salvatorine* and *teguine* are used as family names of people; and *teguine* also appears in some books about Wolof language.

Here is a usage of *tupinambine* in a relevant context in zoology:

> No tupinambine species presently inhabits the region of the fossil locality. The fossils represent the westernmost distribution of fossil tupinambine teiids in Patagonia, enlarging the known geographical distribution of the teiids through the Miocene in a longitudinal range. 
> <sub>Brizuela, S., & Albino, A. M. (2008). Tupinambine teiids from the middle Miocene of north-western Patagonia (Argentina), Amphibia-Reptilia, 29(3), 425-431. doi: https://doi.org/10.1163/156853808785112110</sub>

Note: The common animal adjectives usually entered English from Latin; like bovine  from Latin *bovīnus*, < *bōs, bov-* ox, corvine from Latin *corvīnus*, < *corvus* raven. *Tegu*, on the other hand, comes from Aztec *tecoixin, tecouixin* a lizard. The animal adjectives are usually formed with *-ine* suffix where not all of them come from Latin; and *OED* provides the explanation below for the usage of *-ine* suffix in zoology:

> The termination is widely used in natural history and zoology in forming adjectives, with or without a Latin model, on the names of genera, as *acarine, accipitrine, bovine, caprine, equine, feline, hystricine, murine, passerine, viverrine*; in later use many are modelled on scientific Latin group names (based on the names of genera) with the plural ending *-ina* (neuter plural, originally with Latin a*nimalia* understood) or *-inae* (feminine plural, originally with Latin *bestiae* understood; later as a formal taxonomic ending for subfamily names, after the pattern of *-idae* used for family names), as *gadine, lambeosaurine, mastodontine, milleporine, paradoxurine, pythonine*.